# JavaFX Gridpane replacement while panning/scrolling

Tags: javafx, gridpane

Currently, I'm trying to implement panning on a (game) map, the visual part of which is a gridpane. Since the underlying data model may specify a huge map, I only want to show a small (say 40x40) tile map. When I pan/scroll the map, I currently set the map to null and replace it with a new gridpane containing the new content. I've noticed that this is somewhat laggy, possibly because I want it to keep replacing gridpanes as I'm dragging the map. Which means that every 50 pixels I drag reloads the entire gridpane again.

Is there a more efficient way to change the gridpane's content? I tried implementing a solution that only loads a row or column (depending on whether I'm panning north/east/south/west), but that seemed worse, or as bad, since there doesn't seem to be an efficient way of doing that in a gridpane afaik. Should I even be using a gridpane for this? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to create your own layout to make this efficient. Cache some cells around the part that is actually displayed, etc. It is not a trivial task. [This repo](https://github.com/FXMisc/Flowless) may give you some ideas, though it works only for horizontal *or* vertical scrolling, whereas I think you are looking for both.

Comment: We can't tell you why your solution is not working efficiently without inspecting the code, but loading row/column-wise seems the correct way to go. `GridPane`is probably a good layout for arranging your content, if used correctly...

Comment: I threw the row-column part away since it wasn't working :-) Will try to reimplement it and update with some code here.